# Deleting project Include paths from Eclipse/SystemWorkbench project?

Tags: eclipse, include-path

I'm trying to play with SystemWorkbench, based on Eclipse, and after adding and then deleting paths under

- ($project)/Properties/C/C++ Build/Settings/Tool Settings/MCU GCC Compiler/Includes (empty now)
- ($project)/Properties/C/C++ General/Paths and Symbols/Includes/Languages (GNU C)/Include directories (empty now)

... the project now shows these three includes:

[image]

... and additionally, during build, those same includes are added via -I, unfortunately they are apparently wrong, and so I'd like to delete them. I cannot do this from the GUI (at least not via right-click), and the abovementioned include paths settings in the GUI are empty.

So, how can I delete these include paths, so I can setup new ones?

Answer (score 0):

Seemingly, in the `.cproject` file, there were still hanging nodes of type `<listOptionValue builtIn= ...` under:

```xml
                            <tool id="fr.ac6.managedbuild.tool.gnu.cross.c.compiler.1529590206" name="MCU GCC Compiler" superClass="fr.ac6.managedbuild.tool.gnu.cross.c.compiler.602008433">
                                <option id="gnu.c.compiler.option.include.paths.1440641627" name="Include paths (-I)" superClass="gnu.c.compiler.option.include.paths" useByScannerDiscovery="false" valueType="includePath">
```

and

```xml
                            <tool id="fr.ac6.managedbuild.tool.gnu.cross.c.compiler.1831817711" name="MCU GCC Compiler" superClass="fr.ac6.managedbuild.tool.gnu.cross.c.compiler.1529590206">
                                <option id="gnu.c.compiler.option.include.paths.696630378" name="Include paths (-I)" superClass="gnu.c.compiler.option.include.paths" useByScannerDiscovery="false" valueType="includePath">
```

Close System Workbench, delete those hanging nodes from `.cproject` file and save it, restart System Workbench - yup, now that entire Includes node from the screenshot is gone.